How to generate multiple ApiClients with different base paths so each client can consume different services with openapi-generator in Gradle
I'm trying to generate two different clients with openapi-generator using the Gradle plugin in a springboot project, each client has its own spec.yaml and each spec.yaml has its own path for server.url
When I run openapi generator, it seems like it runs twice to generate the ApiClient class and overrides the base path of the first client configuration that was run.
I need to have a different base path for each client so I can call multiple APIs from the same service.
spec files for the clients
spec for the first client
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: FirstClient
  description: Client
  version: 1.0.0
tags:
    - name: FirstClient
servers:
  - url: https://testTarget:8080/api/v1
paths:
  /helloClient:
    get:
      summary: Get a hello world
      description: Get a hello world client
      tags:
        - FirstClient
      operationId: getHelloWorldClient
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Hello World
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string

spec for the second client
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: SecondClient
  description: Test Spec
  version: 1.0.0
tags:
    - name: SecondClient
servers:
  - url: https://anotherTestTarget:8080/api/v1
paths:
  /testEndpoint:
    get:
      summary: Get a hello world
      description: Get a hello world client
      tags:
        - SecondClient
      operationId: getTestEndpoint
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Hello World
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string

Gradle Clients Config
tasks.register('generateFirstClient', GenerateTask) {
    generatorName.set("java")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/src/main/resources/static/openapi/client-api-docs.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$rootDir/build/generated-sources")
    templateDir.set("$rootDir/src/main/resources/static/openapi/templates")
    configOptions.set([
            library: "webclient",
            dateLibrary: "java8",
            useTags: "true",
            openapiNullable: "false",
            generateModelDocumentation: "true",
            generateModelTests: "true",
            generateApiDocumentation: "true",
            generateApiTests: "true",
            useSpringBoot3: "true",
            useLombok: "true",
            generateBuilders: "true",
    ])
}

tasks.register('generateSecondClient', GenerateTask) {
    generatorName.set("java")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/src/main/resources/static/openapi/test-client-api-docs.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$rootDir/build/generated-sources")
    templateDir.set("$rootDir/src/main/resources/static/openapi/templates")
    configOptions.set([
            library: "webclient",
            dateLibrary: "java8",
            openapiNullable: "false",
            generateModelDocumentation: "true",
            generateModelTests: "true",
            generateApiDocumentation: "true",
            generateApiTests: "true",
            useSpringBoot3: "true",
            useLombok: "true",
            generateBuilders: "true",
    ])
}

After the generation finished I endup with the next files:
Generated API
The problem is that only one base path is added to the class ApiClient and FirstClientApi and SecondClientApi don't overwrite the base path so they can call each to their own server.
Is there a way to set this up so each client can have a different base path each as specified in the spec.yaml?
